# Grails file download not working

Tags: grails

I am trying to write a controller to download a file.
My domain class looks like this:

```
class File {

String fileName
Byte[] fileBytes
Long fileSize
String fileType
String fileDescription
...
...
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
def downloadFile = {
    def file = File.findById(params.id)
    if (file != null)
    {
        response.setContentType(file.fileType)
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"${file.fileName}\"")
        response.outputStream << file.fileBytes
        return
     }
```

}

There's no error but this doesn't work. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some snippet on it long time back.

http://lalitagarw.blogspot.com/2014/03/grails-forcing-file-download.html

This could help you.

However, try adding

```
response.outputStream << file.fileBytes
webRequest.renderView = false
```

and no need for return.

Answer (score 0):

Add a flush at the end instead of the return:

```
response.outputStream.flush()
```